# QTabWidget - tab icons not in the center

Tags: qt, tabs, widget, icons, tabwidget

I have a QTabWidget with six tabs, and all the tabs have an icon - 
but the icons are not in the center of the tab:

[image: TabIcons]

What I've done so far :

```
tabWidget->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab {width: 40px; height: 40px;}"
                        "QTabBar::tab:selected {background: lightblue;}");
tabWidget->setIconSize(QSize(40, 40));
tabWidget->addTab("widget", QIcon("iconPath"), ""); //<--for all six tabs
```

And:

```
tabWidget->setTabIcon(index, QIcon("iconPath"));
```

Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I too have been struggling with this issue. Here is how I resolve it.

**Background:**

I was attempting to get a left side tab menu going, which used icons as its indicators (what the users would see), however I had a problem:

[image]

My icons, which were set using the currentTabIcon in the Property Editor, were aligning to the bottom (which is expected since I am using the [West](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#TabPosition-enum) orientation. Normally, the [North](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#TabPosition-enum) orientation would be selected and the icons would be on the left).

I had this as my stylesheet:

```css
QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background-color: #212121;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected{
    background-color: #313131;
}
QTabBar::tab {
    background-color: #111111; 
    height:70px;
    width: 70px;
    border: none;
}
```

Now, attempting the suggested [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47814762/4628115) found in this post whereby I set the margins did not have the desired effect, infact it had no effect at all.

**Solution:**

After playing around with some of the CSS properties, I discovered that setting the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` gave me the desired result.

[image]

adding the lines:

```css
padding-top: -15px;
padding-bottom: 15px
```

Resolved the problem for me, however this needs to be changed according to your needs.

My final stylesheet resembles:

```css
QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background-color: #212121;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected{
    background-color: #313131;
}
QTabBar::tab {
    background-color: #111111; 
    height:70px;
    width: 70px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: -15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px
}
```

Comment: Thank you KGCyBeX, your solution works to for me, very nice!

Comment: @erniberni glad I could help, thought someone else would benefit from this too

Comment: How did you rotate the images? Did you do that with the stylesheet, code or did you just make your images with a 90 degree turn?

Comment: @DennisW If memory serves, you can do image rotation in CSS. The side bar is actually a `QTabWidget` as you mentioned, with the `tabPosition` property set to `West` (from `North` as default). This rotates (moves) the rendered `QTabWidget` (specifically the TabBar) to the left perimeter of the `QTabWidget` component. This gives the illusion of the icons being rotates, where infact the whole component was rotated. (I think it is a bad design on my part though).

Comment: As far as I know, there's no rotation option in the QT stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

If somebody has the same problem like me with the icons in the tabs, I found a solution after days and days search for this, and its so simple :D

Just add this to the stylesheet for the TabWidget:

```
tabWidget->setStyleSheet("::tab {margin: 0px;}");
                                 ************
```